# Getting all Free Shipping Zones include the default Zone "Rest of the World"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get all data (zone_name, zone_id) when have free shipping zone. I have used :

```
$delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
foreach ((array) $delivery_zones as $key => $the_zone ) {
  echo $the_zone['zone_name'];
}
print_r($delivery_zones);
```

but It always return the result without **Rest of the World** . How I can get all data with all **Free Shipping zones** ?

Answer (score 3):

I got your answer after some search in the [**official thread related to WC 2,6+ and Shipping default Zone**](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wc26-get-all-shipping-zones-and-respective-methods-objects/) and also in the source code of [**`WC_Shipping_Zone`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shipping_Zone.html#7-490) class. You learn that the default class has an **`ID = 0`**.

I have tried this first:

```
$default_zone = new WC_Shipping_Zone(0);
print_r($default_zone);
```

And I got this array:

> WC_Shipping_Zone Object ( [_data:protected] => Array ( [zone_id] => 0 
> **[zone_name] => Rest of the World** [zone_order] => 0 [zone_locations] => Array ( ) ) [_locations_changed:WC_Shipping_Zone:private] => [_cache_group:protected] => [_meta_type:protected] => post [object_id_field_for_meta:protected] => [_meta_data:protected] => Array ( ) [_internal_meta_keys:protected] => Array ( ) )

**Bingo 1! the data is there**  and I get the **default Shipping Zone Object**, but it is **protected** and **not accessible** through a foreach loop or something else…

If you look to [**`WC_Shipping_Zone`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shipping_Zone.html#7-490) you see tha it **extends** [WC_Data](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) class. 
So I have tried to use WC_Data methods with that object, this way:

```
$default_zone = new WC_Shipping_Zone(0);
$default_zone_data = $default_zone->get_data();
print_r($default_zone_data);
```

Bingo 2!!! it outputs the sam array but this time is no protected and accessible.

So the answer is:

```
$default_zone = new WC_Shipping_Zone(0);
$default_zone_data = $default_zone->get_data();

$default_zone_id = $default_zone_data->zone_id;
$default_zone_order = $default_zone_data-> zone_order;
$default_zone_locations = $default_zone_data-> zone_locations;
$default_zone_meta_data = $default_zone_data-> meta_data;

// AND TO FINISH THE THE NAME!!!
$default_zone_name = $default_zone_data->zone_name;

echo $default_zone_name;
```

The output of **`echo $default_zone_name`** is **Rest of the World** (re-bingo !!!)…

The you can use also other [**`WC_Data`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) and [**`WC_Shipping_Zone`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Zone.html) methods to get the needed data:

```
$default_zone = new WC_Shipping_Zone(0);
$default_zone_formatted_location = $default_zone->get_formatted_location();
$default_zone_shipping_methods = $default_zone->get_shipping_methods();

// And so on …
```

Comment: thank your answer but can you help me get **zone_name** and **zone_id** of just **Free Shipping** method ?

Comment: Appriciate your answer. I have found the way getting all value. I will post a answer here and add your skype. thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

thank for answer of @LoicTheAztec . after read him answer, I have found the way to result. here is all:

```
    $zones = array();

    // Rest of the World zone
    $zone                                                   = new \WC_Shipping_Zone( 0 );
    $zones[$zone->get_zone_id()]                            = $zone->get_data();
    $zones[$zone->get_zone_id()]['formatted_zone_location'] = $zone->get_formatted_location();
    $zones[$zone->get_zone_id()]['shipping_methods']        = $zone->get_shipping_methods();

    // Add user configured zones
    $zones = array_merge( $zones, WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones() );
    foreach ( $zones as $each_zone ) {
        $zone_name            = $each_zone['zone_name'];
        $shipping_methods     = $each_zone['shipping_methods'];
        $arr_shipping_methods = json_decode( json_encode( $shipping_methods ), true );
        foreach ( $arr_shipping_methods as $free_shipping ) {
            if ( $free_shipping['id'] == 'free_shipping' ) {
                $zone_id = $each_zone['zone_id'];
            } else {
                echo '';
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I know your assistance and appreciate it. I have vote for your answer.